# Programmatic changes to a view aren't applied

Tags: java, android

I made a list that's loaded with Contact friends and the user can select them by tapping on them. If a person is selected, the listitem's backgorund changes colour, if deselected, the bg colouring goes away.
Problem is, when I call my method on an `OnClickListener`, it's fine. 
When I however call it in a loop to colour already selected friends (e.g. when revisiting the list), it doesn't do the colouring.

The loop that goes through the elements to call `colorize` if needed:

```
for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount();i++){
    ContactFriend cf = (ContactFriend) adapter.getItem(i);
    View v = getViewByPosition(i,listView);
    colorizeFriendBg(v, cf);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

*note I do the exact same in the listener and it works fine there.*

And the colorizer:

```
private void colorizeFriendBg(View v, ContactFriend friend){
    if(friend.isSelected()){
        v.setBackgroundColor(0x993399ff);
    }else{
        v.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    }
    v.invalidate();
}
```

This issue is quite strange and I have no idea what to do in order to make it right. The whole bunch is called from `onActivityCreated`, if that matters.

Edit:

I debugged it of course and the code runs and should change the colour, not running isn't the issue.

Edit again:

here's the listener implementation:

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ContactFriend fr = (ContactFriend) adapter.getItem(position);
            addToSelected(fr);
            //TODO: make it switch some BG colour when clicked. use getViewByPosition.
            View v = getViewByPosition(position,listView);
            colorizeFriendBg(v,fr);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why don't you put the "colorize" method inside the adapter? should be easier

Comment: Because I'm a beginner in Android :D thanks for the tip though I'll do that. 
Do you think it will help resolve this?

Comment: In an old project I did it inside the adapter and it was working correctly, so I guess it will work :) To check better what isn't working in your code, can you add the onclick full code? you can also try calling the "notifyDataSetChanged()" method after changing the color ^^ Let me know so if it doesn't work I can check it better

Comment: I added the listener implementation, but I'll put the colorizer to the adapter. Notify change didn't help though :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what type of item `View` are you getting from the `Adapter`?

that `View` could / should implement `colorize()` and color itself;

for example: `v.colorize(contact.isSelected())` to switch colors.

or with [Android Data-Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) XML (where the viewModel is an instance of `Contact`):

```
<data class="com.acme.databinding.ContactViewHolderBinding">
    <variable name="viewModel" type="com.acme.model.Contact"/>
</data>

...
android:backgroundColor="@{viewModel.isSelected ? R.color.MAGENTA : R.color.BLACK}"
```

class `Contact` just would require a getter **and** a setter for property `isSelected`.

one actually can also bind event handlers, which would be an alternate approach.

Comment: It has `AppCompatTextView`s. I'm moving the colorizer to my adapter now

Comment: @agiro within the `View` it would always color itself, while the `Adapter` provides the items. most often a `ViewHolder` (still of type `View`) is being used. most easy would be to data-bind that single one property: for example: https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-recyclerview-db7c40d9f0e4 < try this tutorial, it should be easy to add alternate background color alike this, based upon the underlying data.

Comment: Thanks, though I still try to figure out why it works on the listener and why it doesn't from within the `for loop`. By the way how do I access a child `View` from an adapter? I found solutions only to get it from outside xd

Comment: @agiro one needs to differ between UI thread and background thread; the `isSelected` is already a property of object `Friend`, there one can data-bind the value easily... added an example above (not tested, but it's meant to be alike that).

Comment: When binding I get a `Error:error: '@{friend.isSelected() ? '993399ff' : '00000000'}' is incompatible with attribute android:textColor (attr) reference|color.` I think though that the whole stuff should have been built towards binding :( I might have to reconsider some stuff here

Comment: your can use `R.color.MAGENTA` and `R.color.BLACK`; color resource ids - or `Drawable`, too ...it merely says, that `reference` or `color` are expected there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `invalidate()` on your view to make the color changes visible.

`invalidate()` forces a redraw with the new colors.

Comment: added `v.invalidate()` at the end of my colorizer, still no luck :/